# Django Rest Framework object is not iterable?

Tags: python, django

I have serialised one of my models that has a foreign key in. I get `'Parent' object is not iterable`

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    # Parent data

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent)
```

serializer.py

```
class ChildSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ReportField
        fields = (
            'id',
            'parent'
        )
```

api.py

```
class ChildList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        child = Child.objects.all()
        serialized_child = ChildSerializers(child, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_child.data)
```

Im guessing i have to pass the parent list to the child list but not sure of the best way to do it

attempt api.py

```
class ChildList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        child = Child.objects.all()
        parent = Parent.objects.all()
        serialized_child = ChildSerializers(child, many=True)
        serialized_parent = ChildSerializers(parent, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_child.data, serialized_parent.data)
```

Comment: Why using `many=True`. `Parent` is just a single field, no need to use explicit serializer field. Just get rid of these `many=True`..

Comment: I misunderstood the docs in the same way.

Comment: Yeah, just remove those many=True, also works for me

Comment: @mariodev could you please make your comment as the answer. I feel like I am taking credits of your answer.

Answer (score 50):

Why using many=True. Parent is just a single field, no need to use explicit serializer field. Just get rid of these many=True

-answered by [mariodev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566605/mariodev) in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do something like this using python collections as an intermediate

#serializers.py
class TimelineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    childs= childSerializer(many=True)
    parents = parentSerializer(many=True)

#apiviews.py
from collections import namedtuple
Timeline = namedtuple('Timeline', ('childs', 'parents'))

def list(self, request):
        timeline = Timeline(
            childs=Child.objects.all(),
            parents=Parent.objects.all(),
        )
        serializer = TimelineSerializer(timeline)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using a ModalSerializer then you have two foreign keys in a modal, then use "to_representation" function like this

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['pcatalog_name'] = CatalogSerializer(instance.pcatalog_name).data
        rep['pcategory_name'] = CategorySerializer(instance.pcategory_name).data
        return rep
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ForeignKey by ManyToManyField to clarify the serializer field with many = True

[image]