# Django 'model' object is not iterable when response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I have 2 model. And the two models are connected to the ManyToManyField.

models.py

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    title = models.TextField()
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('CommentModel')
class CommentModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
```

and serializers.py

```
class CommentModel_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MainCommentModel
        fields = '__all__'

class PostModel_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment = MainCommentModel_serializer(many=True, allow_null=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MainModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

and views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getPost(request, pk):
    post = PostModel.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    comment_list = CommentModel.objects.filter(post_id=post.id)
    for i in comments_list:
        post.comments.add(i)
    serializer = PostModel_serializer(post, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

There is an error when I make a request.

```
'PostModel' object is not iterable
```

and The trackback points here.

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

I tried to modify a lot of code but I can't find solutions.

Please tell me where and how it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702695), you should remove `many=True` in `PostModel_serializer`.

Also it should be `comment_list` not `comments_list`.

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getPost(request, pk):
    post = PostModel.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    comment_list = CommentModel.objects.filter(post_id=post.id)
    for i in comment_list:
        post.comments.add(i)
    serializer = PostModel_serializer(post)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did wrong while creating `ManyToManyField()`.

Instead of this:

```
comments = models.ManyToManyField('CommentModel') #Here you made mistake. you should not add single quote to CommentModel. I think that's why you got that error
```

Try this:

```
comments = models.ManyToManyField(CommentModel)
```

Comment: if i make like your solution, i can't ForeignKey in CommentModel. because 'Unresolved reference 'PostModel' or 'CommentModel''

Comment: have you tried that

Comment: yes. and error. 'Unresolved reference 'CommentModel''. becuase CommentModel is in the lower row.