# Try to Return dataset as a table with request of postman

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I wanna Request with postman and get a table of all books as return but I can't find a way to do this. Thanks a lot

This is my model of books:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And This is my View:

```
class AddBookAPIView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'book.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login/'))
    def post(self, request):
        book_serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if book_serializer.is_valid():
            book_serializer.save()
            return redirect('home')

        return Response({'message': book_serializer.errors})

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login/'))
    def get(self, request):
        book = Book()
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'book': book})
```

And this is my Template(I try make another url for showing all books and I think template is worng too):

```
{% load rest_framework %}
<title> Books </title>

{% block title %}<h3> View Books </h3>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form class="form-inline" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can simply apply `@method_decorator` just above the class itself using `name="dispatch'`.

Secondly, try to use `many=True` in `BookSerializer` and also use `Book.objects.all()` to retrieve all instances of `Book` model, like the following:

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login/'), name='dispatch')
class AddBookAPIView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'book.html'

    def post(self, request):
        book_serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if book_serializer.is_valid():
            book_serializer.save()
            return redirect('home')

        return Response({'message': book_serializer.errors})

    def get(self, request):
        book = Book.objects.all()
        serializer = BookSerializer(book, many=True)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'books': serializer.data})
```

Try to modify the template so that it would show the list of all books, like the following:

```html
{% load rest_framework %}
<title>Books</title>

{% block title %}
    <h3>View Books</h3>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Publication Date</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for book in books %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ book.publication_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ book.publisher }}</td>
                    <td>{{ book.description }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I rtied it but I get this error: 'ListSerializer' object is not iterable

Comment: @Amir Try edited answer, use `serializer.data`.

Comment: I edited the template but there's no data in the tabel!!

Comment: @Amir Make sure you're using `{% for book in books %}`, I changed `book` to `books` in `Response`, see it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, What does `many=True` do?? and there's problem `{{ book.publisher }}` only show id of publishers not name i tried `book.publisher.name` and `book.publisher__name` but no hope!

Comment: @Amir Refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74613214/17562044) for `many=True` it again points to another question and for publisher details, let me edit the answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252416/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-amir).